# D3.js - selection knowing part of an attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have to select SVG elements with a specific `transform` attribute, knowing just a part of it. Let me better explain with an example.
These are the elements I'd like to select:

```
<g transform='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96, 217.04, 43.052)'></g>
<g transform='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96, 317.04  53.052)'></g>
<g transform='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96, 417.04, 63.052)'></g>
<g transform='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96, 517.04, 73.052)'></g>
<g transform='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96, 617.04, 83.052)'></g>
```

I want to select them all and (initially) using something like the code below did sound like a good idea:

```
d3.selectAll("g").filter("[transform='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96)]'");
```

The problem is that, obliviously, the selection is returned as empty and I am wondering how can I tell to d3 to select just those `<g>` elements with a match on the first 4 parameters of the transform attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966125/using-indexof-to-filter-an-array

Comment: Not so clear @Aaron. How could I use indexOf in my case?

Comment: Current answer is better.  It can be done but not worth it with what you already have below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the initial selection of the `g`s and the filtering in one selector:

```
d3.selectAll("g[transform^='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96']");
```

Note the use of the `^=` in the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> **[attr^=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr the value of which is prefixed by "value".

Working demo:

```js
var filtered = d3.selectAll("g[transform^='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96']");
console.log(filtered.size());  // 3: The first three groups
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg>
  <g transform="matrix(96, 0, 0, -96, 217.04, 43.052)"></g>
  <g transform="matrix(96, 0, 0, -96, 317.04  53.052)"></g>
  <g transform="matrix(96, 0, 0, -96, 417.04, 63.052)"></g>
  <g transform="matrix(10, 0, 0, -96, 517.04, 73.052)"></g> <!--different transform-->
  <g transform="matrix(20, 0, 0, -96, 617.04, 83.052)"></g> <!--different transform-->
</svg>
```

---

Of course, you can also split the filtering from the groups' selection:

```
d3.selectAll("g").filter("[transform^='matrix(96, 0, 0, -96']");
```

---

Or, for even more control of the filtering, you can supply a filter function to [`selection.filter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter) whereby getting access to the selected elements as well as the data bound to them.

```
d3.selectAll("g")
  .filter(function(d, i, nodes) {   // Most versatile approach
    return d3.select(this)
      .attr("transform")
        .startsWith("matrix(96, 0, 0, -96");
        // .lastIndexOf("matrix(96, 0, 0, -96", 0);  // For those on IE
  });
```

---

Although all of these solutions will yield the same result, the right one for your problem will likely be a trade-off between performance, simplicity and versatility.